Flutter Dart - There was a problem while parsing the package
After try open .apk file with open_file_plus 3.4.1+1  get this alert message
There was a problem while parsing the package
In AndroidManifest.xml  I have:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
    
<provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
                  android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileProvider"
                  android:exported="false"
                  android:grantUriPermissions="true"
                  tools:replace="android:authorities">
<meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                       android:resource="@xml/filepaths"
                       tools:replace="android:resource" />

Note:
Open  .jpg or .png work fine only .apk is problem.
Any solution?
